# What are the beeping coffins for?

Tags: remnant-2

On [N'Erud](https://remnant2.wiki.fextralife.com/N%27Erud) there are a number, I've found about 5, of these boxes you can interact with and they start beeping.

They look like this..

[image: Small coffin with orange lights]

What are these for and how many do I need to activate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a guide for these today. https://gamerant.com/remnant-2-nerud-coffin-pod-abyssal-rift-eon-vault-phantom-wasteland-timeless-horizon-open-how-rewards-supply-ship-evet/

Firstly you need to roll either campaign or adventure mode until the coffins appear, as they will not appear on every roll of N'Erud.

There are a total of five to find and activate.

Then you must activate the Supply Ship in the Silo area near to the Dark Conduit dungeon. This is done by going into the dungeon to activate the fuses. Then you can interact with the console in the Silo.

Once the ship collects the pods the rewards are available at the bottom of the silo.